# Snes9x-GTK freezing on Ubuntu 13.10 while try to open roms

Tags: 13.10, ppa

I just install the snes9x-gtk from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~bearoso/+archive/ppa) on Ubuntu 13.10. But, when i try to open a rom file, the snes9x-gtk frezes and I'm getting this message:

```
Fontconfig warning: "/etc/fonts/conf.d/50-user.conf", line 14: reading configurations from ~/.fonts.conf is deprecated.
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2239:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Conexão recusada (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Conexão recusada (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Conexão recusada (111)
bt_audio_service_open: connect() failed: Conexão recusada (111)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:961:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) The dmix plugin supports only playback stream
Cannot connect to server socket err = Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado
Cannot connect to server request channel
jack server is not running or cannot be started
Sound buffer size: 4096 (1024 samples)
PortAudio sound driver initializing...
--> (ALSA : default, latency 32ms)...OK
Map_LoROMMap
```

Have someone any ideas what could be happening !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works fine when I chose SDL as Sound Driver !! ;p